# Ubuntu.Components version 1.1 is not installed

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

Anyone knows why I'm getting this error?

[image]

I do have Ubuntu Components in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml`

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Installed the SDK through the PPA. Last time I installed SDK from the default repository, it worked well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Components 1.1 is not available for Ubuntu 14.04.
You have to upgrade to 14.10

Comment: Is there perhaps a PPA I can use to get this?  I cannot upgrade to 14.10, but still would like to use Ubuntu.Components 1.1.  (Background: I'm trying out PhoneGap, trying to build a Ubuntu desktop app, using the instructions from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_ubuntu_index.md.html#Ubuntu%20Platform%20Guide.  That platform uses Ubuntu.Components 1.1.)  Thanks!